Observable and unobservable subspace
In control theory, the set of unobservable states is defined as $\operatorname{Ker}(W)$, where $W$ is the observability Gramian. Thus, the set of unobservable states is also a subspace.
Is it correct to say that the set of observable states is $\mathbb R^n\backslash \operatorname{Ker}(W)$ (which is not a subspace)?
Why do we define the unobservable space instead of the observable space (as in the controllability case)? If I call $\operatorname{Im}(W)$ the observable set/subspace and thus the unobservable set $\mathbb R^n\backslash \operatorname{Im}(W)$ (which is not a subspace), would this definition have a physical intuition?
I'm also confused because I recall some references stating that we can decompose a system into its observable and unobservable subspaces, which are referred to be orthogonal complements to each other. Is this related to the definitions above?

Just as a clarification, was your intent to write a quotient $/$ or a set minus $\setminus$? I assume quotient.

It is a set minus!

It doesn't make perfect sense to label a state as observable or unobservable. This is essentially the point of the Kalman decomposition: each state has an observable component and an unobservable component. If the observable component of a state is $0$, then the state is contained in the unobservable subspace; if the unobservable component of a state is $0$, then the state is contained in the observable subspace. Note that the $0$ state is trivially contained in both the observable and unobservable subspaces of any system. As you mention, the observable and unobservable subspaces are orthogonal complements. It is entirely possible for a nontrivial state to have observable and unobservable components: only the observable component determines the output of the system.
Denote $w$ as the unobservable subspace and $w^\perp$ as the observable subspace. Denote the observability transform by $Q$, with matrix representation given by $\begin{pmatrix} C \\ C A \\ \vdots \\ C A^{n - 1} \end{pmatrix}$. Note that ${\rm Im} Q$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, where the output space is $\mathbb{R}^k$ (i.e., the state-to-output transform is $C: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$). In particular, ${\rm Im} Q$ does not live in the state space $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general, so it does not make sense to say that it is the "observable set/subspace" - and I am not personally aware of a good intuition for what it physically represents. However, by the rank-nullity theorem, we of course have that the dimension of the observable subspace $w^\perp$ is equal to the dimension of ${\rm Im} Q$:
$$\dim w^\perp = n - \dim w = n - \dim {\rm Ker} Q = \dim {\rm Im} Q$$
It is more convenient to define the unobservable subspace because these are the states that cannot be distinguished using the output (all of them being mapped to $0$ by $Q$). In contrast, when considering controllable/uncontrollable subspaces, it is more convenient to consider the image of the input-state transform $P$ with matrix representation $\begin{pmatrix} B & A B & \cdots & A^{n - 1} B \end{pmatrix}$, because these are the states that can be attained by modifying the input.

The answer was very clear, thank you. I understand that the row space of $Q$ is equivalent to the image space of $W$. Could you elaborate on why $\operatorname{Im}(Q)$ is a subspace of the output space? Is it because the column space of $Q$ is contained in $\mathbb R^n$?

Glad it was helpful. I made a mistake; ${\rm Im} Q$ (equivalently the column space of its matrix representation $\hat{Q}$) is not a subspace of the output space (I will fix this); it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n k}$, where $\mathbb{R}^k$ is the codomain of the output matrix $C A^j$ for $j \in {0, \dots, n - 1}$. I do not know of a good physical intuition for that space. The domain of $Q$ is the state space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
